# DynamicLinks iOS: await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink() works on debug, but doesn't work on release mode

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink() works in debug mode, but doesn't work in release mode on iOS.

await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink() work fine for android debug and release mode but  when i use dynamic link in debug mode it work fine but when i create release mode for app this will return always null. not getting after sometimes of wait because i research on that issue somebody getting link after some wait of times but in my case it will not return any link after wait of sometimes.

I spent a day for finding the solution for that but nothing work for me. I tried all most the solution which mention in #2660  #4548 #3450 but not work any solution for me.

### Project Files

```
export const getInitialLink = async ()=> {
  const link = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();
  const id = onHandleDynamicLink(link);
  return id;
};

export const onHandleDynamicLink = link => {
  if (link) {
    const linkUrl = url.parse(link.url, true);
    const VideoId = linkUrl.path.split('/')[2];
    return VideoId;
  }
  return null;
};

import {getInitialLink} from '../../helpers/dynamicLinksHelper';
const Id = await getInitialLink();`
```

`package.json`:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^16.4.6",
 "react-native": "0.64.2",
```

iOS

## source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

```
target 'project' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  # pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  # pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

  # pod 'RNAWSCognito', :path => '../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js'

  # pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"

  # pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

  target 'newslineisitanywayTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

##### AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <RNFBDynamicLinksAppDelegateInterceptor.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
@import Firebase;
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>


static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [RNFBDynamicLinksAppDelegateInterceptor sharedInstance];
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif`your text`
  
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
  
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"newslineisitanyway"
                                            initialProperties:appProperties];
  
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }
  
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                         openURL:url
                                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                      annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}


// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
// [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
//  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
// [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
//  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  RNFBDynamicLinksAppDelegateInterceptor *interceptor = [RNFBDynamicLinksAppDelegateInterceptor sharedInstance];
      if (url && !interceptor.initialLinkUrl)
      {
          FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
          if (dynamicLink.url)
          {
              interceptor.initialLinkUrl = dynamicLink.url.absoluteString;
              interceptor.initialLinkMinimumAppVersion = dynamicLink.minimumAppVersion == nil ? [NSNull null] : dynamicLink.minimumAppVersion;
          }
      }
      return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
      return YES;
  
}

@end`
```

### Environment

**`react-native info` output:**

- **Platform that you're experiencing the issue on**:

  - [x] iOS`your text`
- **Are you using `TypeScript`?**

  - NO

---